# Converting Personal geodatabase to GML format using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, file-geodatabase, gml, data-interoperability

I am working on ArcGIS 10.3.

Does anyone know how to convert a personal geodatabase into a GML format?

Comment: I Think you need the Data Interoperability Extension, see for example this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21153/how-do-i-convert-gml-to-esri-featureclasses

Comment: I just checked it looks like I do not have the Interoperability tool extension. Is there any Python code that I can use to convert it?

Comment: If you read the answer of the link you will see that you only need to install it, you dont need to enable it. The second answer shows how to do it using Open Source.

Comment: You could convert the geodatabase features to shapefile and then use ogr.  See this link https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178280/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-shp-file-to-gml.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of GML->FC, it's the reverse!